# The beautifull Misfit Mountains of Argentina

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

In **Germany**, everyone drinks an **Angry Mojito**

If you go to **France**, you should get an **Elastic Mohawk**

In the **UK**, chewing a **Tame Mint** is quite common

Don't go to **USA** without your **Damp Tissue** for emergencies

**Denmark** is famous for it's **Long, Lumpy Rollerblades** as means of transportation

When you're in **Israel** Don't be surprised if you find a **Beany Narcissus** behind every rock

---

Question:

What's a common food in **Canada**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The names :

> contain the First letters of the president/prime-minister basically the leader of the government of the respective countries.

---

Germany

> Angry Mojito : **A**ngela **M**erkel

France

> Elastic Mohawk : **E**mmanuel **M**acron

UK

> Tame Mint : **T**heresa **M**ay

USA

> Damp Tissue : **D**onald **T**rump

Denmark

> Lumpy Rollerblades : **L**ars **R**asmussen

Israel

> Beany Narcissus : **B**enjamin **N**etanyahu

---

Canada has:

> Justin Trudeau so something like [J.T.](http://www.completecocktails.com/Drinks/J.T..aspx#.Whh47kqWY2w) or maybe Jager Tonic.

Comment: The answer is neither a food nor is it grammatical, but you got the point :)

Comment: Haha, and meanwhile I was trying the recipe for tonic ;)

Comment: Maybe Wryyl Gehssyrf?